# ApplicationInsights: "TelemetryChannel found a telemetry item without an InstrumentationKey", but I'm using recommended ConnectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-application-insights, appinsights

.NET6, `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` version **2.21.0**

My AppInsights works, but I also have this trace warning in Azure:

> AI: TelemetryChannel found a telemetry item without an InstrumentationKey. This is a required field and must be set in either your config file or at application startup.

How to fix it?

I'm using recommended `ConnectionString` (instead of `InstrumentationKey`).

My `appsettings.json`:

```json
"ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=xxxx;IngestionEndpoint=https://yyy.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://zzz.azure.com/",
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
    }
}
```

My `startup.cs`:

```
// AppInsights options
var aiOptions = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
{
    EnableDependencyTrackingTelemetryModule = false,
};

services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to Integrate `Application Insights` in `.NET Core6` Web App using the `Application Insights Connection String` and able to see the traces without any warnings.

- You are writing the code in`Startup.cs`, `.NET 6` doesn't require `Startup.cs` file, the code can be configured within the `Program.cs` file.
- In [.NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model) both `Program.cs` and `Startup.cs` configurations are unified into a single file  `Program.cs`.

***My appsettings.json***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=****;IngestionEndpoint=https://*****.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://****.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  }
}
```

***Program.cs***

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var aiOptions = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
{
    EnableDependencyTrackingTelemetryModule = false,
};
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var app = builder.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();
```

***Traces for MVC***

```cs
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Log Information from Controller.");
            _logger.LogDebug("Debug Message from the Controller.");
            _logger.LogWarning("Log Warning.");
            _logger.LogError("Log Error.");
            return View();
        }
```

***Traces for Web App***

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
ILogger logger = app.Logger;
logger.LogInformation("Test logs");
logger.LogWarning("Iam a Warning Message");
```

***Traces for MVC App***
[image]

***Traces for Web App***
[image]

Comment: This is from your localhost or AppService from Azure?
I have this warning only on AppServices (Linux Docker) every 15 minutes, in localhost on Windows I don't see these.

Comment: This is from local host. Will try with the `Azure Linux App service` and let you know.

Comment: ping. I still have this